# pm2 can't fork nodejs which is contain origin cluster code

Tags: node.js, pm2

my app is one using origin nodejs cluster code inside ,and run by node ./dist/main.js fine
but it go wrong when i use pm2 start ./dist/main.js

```
//my code

import cluster from 'cluster'
import http from 'http'

if(cluster.isMaster){
    (async()=>{
        const master = await (await import('./master'))
        async function onMsg(pid:number,type?:string,num?:number,data?:{db:any,apiName:any,args:Array<any>}){
            console.log(`master receiving message from cluster ${pid}`)
            try{
                let result = await master.publishMission(type,data)
                // console.log(`${type} finish mission and send back to koa cluster ${pid}`)
                cluster.workers[pid].send({num:num,status:true,data:result})
            }catch(err){
                cluster.workers[pid].send({num:num,err})
            }
        }
        //cluster nums
        for(let i=0;i<1;i++){
            cluster.fork()
        }
        cluster.on('message',(worker,msg)=>{
            onMsg(worker.id,...msg)
        })
        cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
            console.log('worker %d died (%s). restarting...',worker.process.pid, signal || code);
            cluster.fork();
          });
    })()
}else{
    (async()=>{
        const app = await (await import('./app')).app
        try{
            http.createServer(app).listen(5000)`enter code here`
            console.log("fork new koa server",process.pid)
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })()
}
```

//error log
TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\yany\project\Jmrh_Warehouse\src\main.ts:22:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Worker. (internal/cluster/master.js:174:13)
at Worker.emit (events.js:315:20)
at ChildProcess. (internal/cluster/worker.js:32:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
at emit (internal/child_process.js:903:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\yany\project\Jmrh_Warehouse\src\main.ts:22:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Worker. (internal/cluster/master.js:174:13)
at Worker.emit (events.js:315:20)
at ChildProcess. (internal/cluster/worker.js:32:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
at emit (internal/child_process.js:903:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)

Answer (score 1):

pm2 implements clusters internally.

So there're may be a problem with the port sharing.

Where: `dist/main.js` is

```
(async()=>{
        const app = await (await import('./app')).app
        try{
            http.createServer(app).listen(5000)`enter code here`
            console.log("fork new koa server",process.pid)
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })()
```

`pm2 start dist/main.js -i max` might work.  `-i` starts pm2 in cluster mode.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Answer (score 0):

by use `pm2 start dist/main.js -i 1` this error end

so when use pm2 fork it may disable cluster message transform inside

but new problem come out

```
const master = await (await import('./master'))
```

this code don't work

it's fine when I use node dist/main.js but can't work in pm2

```
import * as cl from 'child_process'
import {EventEmitter} from 'events'

const event = new EventEmitter()
const autoReboot = false
var count = 0

console.log("fine")

interface masterStore{
    [typeOfChild:string]:{
        childGroup?:Array<cl.ChildProcess>,
        workIndex:number,
        maxNum?:number,
    }
}

var master:masterStore={}

//child process of database
master['mongodb'] = {
    childGroup:[],
    workIndex:0,
    maxNum:1
}

for(let i =0;i<master['mongodb'].maxNum;i++){
    forkNewDB()
}

function forkNewDB(){
    var db = cl.fork(`${__dirname}/data/index.js`)
    master['mongodb'].childGroup.push(db)
    db.on('exit',(signal)=>{
        console.log(`db process ${db.pid} exit with code ${signal}`)
        let index = master['mongodb'].childGroup.findIndex(el=>el.pid==db.pid)
        master['mongodb'].childGroup.splice(index,1)
        if(autoReboot){
            forkNewDB()
        }
    })
    db.on('message',async (msg:{des:string,type:string,ev:string,result?:any,err?:any,data?:any,num?:any})=>{
        if(msg.des=="res"){
            event.emit(msg.ev,{msg})
        }else{
            try{
                let result = await publishMission(msg.type,msg.data)
                db.send({des:"res",num:msg.num,status:true,data:result})
            }catch(err){
                db.send({des:"res",num:msg.num,err})
            }
            
        }
    })
}

//child process of rabbitmq
master['rabbitmq'] = {
    childGroup:[],
    workIndex:0,
    maxNum:1
}

function forkNewMQ(){
    var mq = cl.fork(`${__dirname}/mq/index.js`)
    master['rabbitmq'].childGroup.push(mq)
    mq.on('exit',(signal)=>{
        console.log(`mq process ${mq.pid} exit with code ${signal}`)
        master['rabbitmq'].childGroup.splice(0,1)
        if(autoReboot){
            forkNewMQ()
        }
    })
    mq.on('message',async (msg:{des:string,type:string,ev:string,result?:any,err?:any,data?:any,num?:any})=>{
        if(msg.des=="res"){
            event.emit(msg.ev,{msg})
        }else{
            try{
                let result = await publishMission(msg.type,msg.data)
                mq.send({des:"res",num:msg.num,status:true,data:result})
            }catch(err){
                mq.send({des:"res",num:msg.num,err})
            }
            
        }
    })
}

forkNewMQ()


//child process of redis
master['redis'] = {
    childGroup:[],
    workIndex:0,
    maxNum:1
}

function forkNewRedis(){
    var redis = cl.fork(`${__dirname}/redis/index.js`)
    master['redis'].childGroup.push(redis)
    redis.on('exit',(signal)=>{
        console.log(`redis process ${redis.pid} exit with code ${signal}`)
        let index = master['redis'].childGroup.findIndex(el=>el.pid==redis.pid)
        master['redis'].childGroup.splice(index,1)
        if(autoReboot){
            forkNewRedis()
        }
    })
    redis.on('message',async (msg:{des:string,type:string,ev:string,result?:any,err?:any,data?:any,num?:any})=>{
        if(msg.des=="res"){
            event.emit(msg.ev,{msg})
        }else{
            try{
                let result = await publishMission(msg.type,msg.data)
                redis.send({des:"res",num:msg.num,status:true,data:result})
            }catch(err){
                redis.send({des:"res",num:msg.num,err})
            }
            
        }
    })
}

forkNewRedis()

//init message publish
function publishMission(type?:string,data?:{db:any,apiName:any,args:Array<any>}):Promise<any>{
    return new Promise(async (res,rej)=>{
        try{
            let tmp = master[type].workIndex
            master[type].workIndex++
            master[type].workIndex=master[type].workIndex%master[type].maxNum
            let ev = count+""
            // console.log(`master publish mission to ${type}`)
            master[type].childGroup[tmp].send({data,ev,des:"req"})
            count++
            event.once(ev,(result)=>{
                if(!result.msg.err){
                    res(result.msg.result)
                }else{
                    rej(result.msg.err)
                }
                event.removeListener(ev,()=>{})
            })
        }catch(err){
            rej(err)
        }
    })
}


export{publishMission}
```

node dist/main log should be

```
fine
child process 10116 rabbitmq is ready
fork new koa server 15948
child process 10008 create DB thread 1
```